# nginx fails to use proxy_pass when handling error

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx to serve up error pages from an s3 bucket.

To that end my configuration looks like this:

```
location / {
    error_page 404 = @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    rewrite ^ /my-s3-bucket/404.html;
    proxy_pass https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com;
}
```

My expectation is that anything that hits the website and is not found is then sent to the @fallback location.  I then want to rewrite the URL with the actual location of my 404 page and send on to the s3 bucket. I don't want to just 302 redirect to the 404 page.

The problem is that the proxy_pass directive is not executed.  Instead, it just looks for my rewritten URL locally.

See my access logs below:

```
2019/01/07 03:05:42 [error] 85#85: *3 open() "/etc/nginx/html/sdfd" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: www.dev.mywebsite.com.au, request: "GET /sdfd HTTP/2.0", host: "www.dev.mywebsite.com.au"
2019/01/07 03:05:42 [error] 85#85: *3 open() "/etc/nginx/html/my-s3-bucket/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: www.dev.mywebsite.com.au, request: "GET /sdfd HTTP/2.0", host: "www.dev.mywebsite.com.au"
```

I made a request to www.dev.mywebsite.com.au/sdfd which wasn't found. 'sdfs' was rewritten to 'my-s3-bucket/404.html' but instead of then proxy passing that to https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com it looks for it in the local /etc/nginx/html directory.

My nginx version is 1.15.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rewrite...break` if you want the rewritten URI to be processed within the same `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

For example:

```
location @fallback {
    rewrite ^ /error/404.html break;
    proxy_pass https://example.com;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The 'break;' is what is required.